# Encode a string to fixed-width unicode UCS-2 in Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-16

I need a fixed-width string encoding. From what I understood, UCS-2 and UCS-4 (also, ASCII) are such fixed-width encodings.

From what I understood, Python only supports a variable-width UTF-16 via `s.encode('utf_16_le')`. Is it true? Is there an easy way to encode into a unicode fixed-width encoding?

Context: I'm storing a string array in raw bytes and need a way to index into it to recover original strings. Index calculation is easier when all characters are fixed-width.

```py
strings = ['asd', 'def']

# ascii
bytelens = list(map(len, strings))
bytes = ''.join(strings).encode('ascii')

# utf8
bytelens = []
bytes = bytearray()
for s in strings:
  e = s.encode('utf-8')
  bytelens.append(len(e))
  bytes.extend(e)

# i need bytelens to later recover original strings from the array bytes
```

As you can see, ASCII variant is very simple, and UTF-8 is more convoluted and 20% slower (probably because of many allocations and function calls). A true fixed-width UCS-2 would be a solution!

A follow-up question: how can I know if my string has characters from UCS-1 / UCS-2 / UCS-4? For UCS-1 there is str.isascii. Any ideas about UCS-2?

Comment: Why do you want to work with `bytes`?

Comment: Because I then load the bytes into a PyTorch tensor to share it between multiprocessing data loader threads: context in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/13246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing various concepts.

In Python, you can just index a string (or an array). It doesn't matter the length of every character. But also in this case, I should warn you that one character is not a single/simple entity: if you need single entities, you should put together more characters (combining characters, e.g. accents, etc.).

UTF16 is variable width, but it is the same as UCS2, but for characters outside UCS2. So for most things, it doesn't matter, and if you have such characters, you just work with sometime low and high surrogates (like on many other computer languages, which supports only UCS2). But this is often not a problem, because you should not split a string at random places, but always at end of an entity.

UCS4 and UTF-32 are practically the same encoding: Unicode code points into 32-bit numbers. (Differences are just virtual, and on some definition, not for Unicode characters [UCS is based on an ISO which allowed more (higher) code-points, never allocated)

Comment: "In Python, you can just index a string (or an array). It doesn't matter the length of every character."

I'd be indexing into one large PyTorch byte array and then recovering the individual string. This is done to avoid problems with shared memory.

Is there a way to make sure that my characters are all fitting into UCS-2? E.g. I'd like to ensure (in a fast way) that all my characters will be encoded as strictly two bytes.

I'd like to avoid the situation when some characters are represented by 1 byte and some - by 2 bytes. That would break index calculations.

Comment: If I get a way to recover UTF-16-encoded byte lengths, my problem would also be solved.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I should 1) ensure that all characters fit into UCS-2, 2) can compute bytelens as `[len(s) * 2 for s in strings]`, right? I know there exists str.isascii. Is there a str.isucs2? I couldn't find it. And iterating over all characters may be slow.

Comment: For the first question: it depends on how you read the bytes. Python strings use a "fixed" length encoding, which may be variable. In other words: in a string, every character has the same length, but if a string is just ASCII [or Latin1], python uses just one byte, if if could use UCS2, it uses UCS2, else it will use UTF-32. Every string may use different "sub-encoding", but every character in a string has same length

Comment: And because strings are read-only, it never cause problems. [You can never change a character in middle of a string, without generating a new string]

Comment: So to me, it may seems you are reimplementing Python string: check larger character, and getting an appropriate string [or maybe you give just an error]. If you want to be safe, just use UTF-32

Comment: "it may seems you are reimplementing Python string": more like reimplementing a list of Python strings. yeah, but unfortunately there're [nasty reasons](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/13246) for this related to multiprocessing.

Oh, UTF-32 should always be fixed-width, right?

Is there a way to read off Python string's [unicode class](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#unicode-type)?

Comment: I came up with a post-factum check for UCS-2: `assert sum(map(len, strings)) * 2 == len(bytes)`. If any character takes more than one 16-bit codepoint, it would break and be clear for user. If you wish to incorporate all this information to the answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @VadimKantorov: I think you could add your answer, because it is much more specific that I interpreted (and answered). So users will have the choice: general or particular. Note: before to edit the answer, I should test your cases for all cases (e.g. ASCII, Chinese, emojii), which I do not find much appealing. Note: you can also do an `assert len(strings) * 2 = len(bytes) [if you have also a test, because it is true just for actual python version, maybe a new PEP will change things] Of you can check your byte sequence for value inside d800-dfff: these are coded into 4bytes UTF-16

Comment: I'll edit your answer and will then mark it as accepted :) Yep, you answered slightly different question than I had posted originally, but nonetheless your explanation about character classes was helpful, and I could find a solution!